# How can I know all available cc_toolchains by default, and how to access info of the selected toolchain in bazel?

Tags: bazel, cc

Bazel seems to be automatically configure the local system and select a cc_toolchain for me. Is there any way I can know of all available toolchain options so that I can choose another one instead of the toolchain chosen by default? (I assume there can be many. For instance, a toolchain with gcc, another one with clang, and so on)
Also, is there any way I can access to the toolchain info, which is chosen for the actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bazel` indeed auto generates a toolchain. Using [`protobuf`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf), if we run a simple `bazel build :protobuf` we end up with a directory `bazel-protobuf/external/local_config_cc/` that is worth exploring. Especially the `BUILD.bazel` inside shows which toolchains are auto detected. https://github.com/limdor/bazel-examples/tree/master/linux_toolchain is a great write up providing some background in addition to the official documentation at https://bazel.build/docs/cc-toolchain-config-reference.

Note that you can let `bazel` auto detect a different compiler by using something like:

```
CC=clang CXX=clang bazel build :protobuf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For cc_toolchain, is it best practice to rely on system installed libs and compilers? I saw many hermetic py_toolchains but not many cc_toolchains

Comment: No, it is not the best practice. But it is difficult to setup a hermetic `cc_toolchain()` and most open-source projects using `bazel` want the user to be able to start quickly with the system compilers.

https://github.com/aspect-build/gcc-toolchain is a hermetic toolchain. Another way is to setup your own based on https://crosstool-ng.github.io/.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had a chance to read an article (https://blog.aspect.dev/hermetic-c-toolchain) from aspect but not totally understand the downside of using the hermetic cc toolchain. What would be the downside of it? Should I have to link all the libraries statically if I decide to use hermetic toolchain?

Comment: That is a question it its own right. From the top of my head: 1) effort to setup a hermetic cc_toolchain 2) download sizes for users that already have a system compiler 3) needs to provide/link against an old version of `libc`/`libc++` 4) makes it harder to quickly play with different compilers/linkers or versions of these tools.